# Moving Javascript variables into Html Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i found this [guide](http://www.codescratcher.com/jquery/create-simple-stock-ticker-using-jquery-yahoo-finance-api/) to create a stock ticker. 
I tried to change it into an html table, but i'm stuck.
So, i  created the table, but i have big problems to divide each variable.
What i want to accomplish is a table with this columns order:

- Symbol: CompName
- Price: Price
- Change: PriceIcon + ChnageInPrice
- %: PercentChnageInPrice
  What i've accomplished for now it's just this, all the content in one column (because of the variable StockTickerHTML i guess) 
  Full Code [Link](http://goo.gl/KhSk69) 
  Can you please help me?

  ```
      var CNames = "^FTSE,FTSEMIB.MI,^IXIC,^N225,^HSI,EURUSD=X";
      var flickerAPI = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22" + CNames + "%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys";
      var StockTickerHTML = "";


      var StockTickerXML = $.get(flickerAPI, function(xml) {
          $(xml).find("quote").each(function () {
              Symbol = $(this).attr("symbol");
              $(this).find("Name").each(function () {
                  CompName = $(this).text();
              });
              $(this).find("LastTradePriceOnly").each(function () {
                  Price = $(this).text();
              });
              $(this).find("Change").each(function () {
                  ChnageInPrice = $(this).text();
              });
              $(this).find("PercentChange").each(function () {
                  PercentChnageInPrice = $(this).text();
              });

              var PriceClass = "GreenText", PriceIcon="up_green";
              if(parseFloat(ChnageInPrice) < 0) { PriceClass = "RedText"; PriceIcon="down_red"; }
              StockTickerHTML = StockTickerHTML + "<span class='" + PriceClass + "'>";
              StockTickerHTML = StockTickerHTML + "<span class='quote'>" + CompName + " </span> ";
              StockTickerHTML = StockTickerHTML + parseFloat(Price).toFixed(2) + " ";
              StockTickerHTML = StockTickerHTML + "<span class='" + PriceIcon + "'></span>" + parseFloat(Math.abs(ChnageInPrice)).toFixed(2) + " (";
              StockTickerHTML = StockTickerHTML + parseFloat( Math.abs(PercentChnageInPrice.split('%')[0])).toFixed(2) + "%)</span> </br>";
          });

          $("#dvStockTicker").html(StockTickerHTML);
          $("#dvStockTicker").jStockTicker({interval: 30, speed: 2});
      });
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be this :
*(see comments in code)*

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  StockPriceTicker();
  setInterval(function() {
    StockPriceTicker();
  }, 2 * 1000); // <------ we refresh each 2 seconds
});

// we get the table's body where 
// the lines will be inserted.
var $body = $('table tbody');

/*
   this will be the cache of 
   our lines, once they are prepared / transformed
   as your need, we will join and insert them
   in the body of our table.
*/
var Lines = [];

/*
  We define a function in charge of creating the HTML
  of each row of hour table, and then push them
  in the array defined above "Lines".
*/
var addLine = function(symbol, price, change, percent) {
  Lines.push('<tr>' +
    '<td class="symbol" >' + symbol  + '</td>' +
    '<td class="price"  >' + price   + '</td>' +
    '<td class="change" >' + change  + '</td>' +
    '<td class="percent">' + percent + '</td>' +
    '</tr>');
};

// this is your function to get data
function StockPriceTicker() {
  var Symbol = "",
      CompName = "",
      Price = "",
      ChnageInPrice = "",
      PercentChnageInPrice = "";

  var CNames = "^FTSE,FTSEMIB.MI,^IXIC,^N225,^HSI,EURUSD=X";
  var flickerAPI = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22" + CNames + "%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys";

  var StockTickerXML = $.get(flickerAPI, function(xml) {
    $(xml).find("quote").each(function() {
      Symbol = $(this).attr("symbol");
      $(this).find("Name").each(function() {
        CompName = $(this).text();
      });
      $(this).find("LastTradePriceOnly").each(function() {
        Price = $(this).text();
      });
      $(this).find("Change").each(function() {
        ChnageInPrice = $(this).text();
      });
      $(this).find("PercentChange").each(function() {
        PercentChnageInPrice = $(this).text();
      });

      var PriceClass = "GreenText",
          PriceIcon = "up_green";

      if (parseFloat(ChnageInPrice) < 0) {
        PriceClass = "RedText";
        PriceIcon = "down_red";
      }

      /*
      
      We create the html to be inserted on each xml loop.
      
        - First : prepare and transform as you need
        - Last  : use the function we define above "addLine";
      */
      
      var htmlSymbol,
          htmlPrice,
          htmlChange,
          htmlPercent;

      htmlSymbol = "<span class='" + PriceClass + "'>";
      htmlSymbol = htmlSymbol + "<span class='quote'>" + CompName + " </span></span>";

      htmlPrice = parseFloat(Price).toFixed(2) + " ";

      htmlChange = parseFloat(Math.abs(ChnageInPrice)).toFixed(2) + "<span class='" + PriceIcon + "'></span>";

      htmlPercent = parseFloat(Math.abs(PercentChnageInPrice.split('%')[0])).toFixed(2) + "%";

      
      // We use here the function defined above.
      addLine(htmlSymbol, htmlPrice, htmlChange, htmlPercent);

    });

    
    /*
       Once the loop of reading the XML
       end, we have pushed all html in the array "Lines".
       So now we delete the content of our table's body, and
       we fill it with all the lines joined.
    */
    $body.empty().html(Lines.join(''));
    
    // we reset the content of Lines for the next interval
    Lines = [];

  });
}
```

```css
.GreenText {
  color: Green;
}
.RedText {
  color: Red;
}
.up_green {
  background: url(http://www.codescratcher.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/up.gif) no-repeat left center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.down_red {
  background: url(http://www.codescratcher.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/down.gif) no-repeat left center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
table {
  border: solid;
  border-color: #666;
}
td {
  padding: 3px;
}
.symbol {
  border: solid 3px #DDD;
}
.price {
  border: solid 3px aqua;
}
.change {
  border: solid 3px yellow;
}
.percent {
  border: solid 3px purple;
}
td.price,
td.change,
td.percent {
  text-align: right;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
  background-color:#EEF;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even){
  background-color:#AAA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class='symbol'>Symbol</th>
        <th class='price'>Price</th>
        <th class='change'>Change</th>
        <th class='percent'>%</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I think i can surely work on this code, thank you very much even for the comments, very very helpful. I have just a problem: i included your fist javascript into my header (between the <script> of course), the second part of your code into the <style> tag, and the third into the <body>... the result is the table with all the css, but i don't see the javascript, so the table is empty... what could it be? never encountered this problem before

Comment: Glad this code help you ! It will be preferable to add the javascript at the end of your document just before the closing tag `</body>`, another thing to check is that you have inserted jQuery. check that and come back to tell me

Comment: You where right: i moved the whole javascript at the bottom page and it worked perfectly fine! My bad, sorry for the inconvenient, and thanks again for all your precious help.

Comment: One last question: do you think that with your precious code it will be possible to add a background color to every row of the column? i will have a table when the first row (tr) has a background color, the second line another color, and so on...? It's not just a simple css thing i guess (i'm already trying)

Comment: yes it is CSS, I have updated my answer to reflect your need : `tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
  background-color:#EEE;
}`

Comment: Can you please explain to me the "nth-child(odd)" code? Thank you very much, it's perfect. You have all my gratitude, i'll study your code to better learn javascript

Comment: it is a [css selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html):  in tbody for each odd tr set background color #EEE ! pure css

Comment: [nth: definition on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: Thank you for the link, now i understand how is it working! thanks for all your help. Much oblidged! Have a nice day :)

Comment: someone said: `knowledge worth only if it is shared by all`,  i agree so i share ! you are welcome ! have a nice day.